# ErrorAccessDenied when using app with all permissions

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, adal

I am using the code from

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-python-flask-webapp-call-graph#register-the-sample-applications-with-your-azure-active-directory-tenant

I have added new functions to make graph api call

```
    def call_ms_graph_email_ext():
      ms_identity_web.acquire_token_silently() 
      graph = app.config['GRAPH_ENDPOINT_MAIL_EXT']
      token = f'Bearer {ms_identity_web.id_data._access_token}'
      results = requests.get(graph, headers={'Authorization': token}).json()
      length = len(results)
      print (results)
      return render_template('auth/call-graph-email.html', results=results)
```

in app_config.py

```
GRAPH_ENDPOINT_MAIL_EXT = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/mailbox1@company1.onmicrosoft.com/messages'
```

The app is having Mail.Read permission for Application user
there is no scope defined in aad.config.json file

```
"auth_request": {
    "redirect_uri": null,
    "scopes": [],
    "response_type": "code"
    },
```

the Graph api in the sample code works fine

```
GRAPH_ENDPOINT = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users'
```

mailbox1@company1.onmicrosoft.com is a shared mailbox i created from MS 365 admin centre

and i am able to access the Graph API for messages using graph explorer . When i use application i get access denied error

```
{'error': {'code': 'ErrorAccessDenied', 'message': 'Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.'}}
```

can someone suggest what is wrong here ?

Comment: Can you please share the query details, that is Client request id and timestamp, so I can check the logs.

Answer (score 1):

I had some problems using the flask code so i am using a different code from

https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-python/blob/dev/sample/confidential_client_secret_sample.py

My requirement is a daemon app i don't need user interaction.

1. Allowed Public client flows in Azure Authentications section.
2. Mail.Read.Write MS graph API - Application permission  to the  app
3. Asked for Admin consent Asked Admin to create restrict policy rule
   for this app
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-limit-mailbox-access
4. Tested i am able to access the shared mailbox from graph API but not any other mailbox which confirms restrict access policy is in force